# How do you filter on specific values of a column in one dataframe based on conditions of another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have two dataframes that look like this:

```
#df1
id   |   count    |  mindate
x         3            01/01/2020
y         4            01/02/2019
z         5            01/03/2019
#df2
id   |   date 
x         01/01/2019   
x         01/02/2019      
x         01/01/2020     
y         01/02/2018
y         01/03/2019
y         01/04/2020
z         01/04/2019
z         01/05/2020
```

What I would like to do is if the count is less than 4 for an id, then I want to I want to keep the dates for that id past the year 2019. If the count for an id is greater than or equal to 4 for an id, then I want to only keep the dates for the id past its mindate value. So the final dataframe should look like this:

```
id   |   date 
x         01/01/2019   
x         01/02/2019      
x         01/01/2020     
y         01/03/2019
y         01/04/2020
z         01/04/2019
z         01/05/2020
```

I have merged the two dataframes but I am not sure what to do after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Left `merge` the dataframe `df2` with `df1` on `id`, then using `np.where` create a boolean mask to filter the rows from `df2`

```
s = df2.merge(df1, on='id', how='left', sort=False)
m = np.where(s['count'] < 4, s['date'].dt.year >= 2019, s['date'] > s['mindate'])
```

---

```
>>> df2[m]

  id       date
0  x 2019-01-01
1  x 2019-01-02
2  x 2020-01-01
4  y 2019-01-03
5  y 2020-01-04
6  z 2019-01-04
7  z 2020-01-05
```

PS: Before using this approach you need to parse the date columns in `df1` and `df2` to `datetime` type.